# Windows Authentication from NGINX on Linux

Tags: iis, nginx, windows-authentication

I'm looking for alternatives to running Internet Information Services (IIS) on Windows, but one of the requirements of this project is the use of Windows Authentication against a Microsoft Active Directory domain.

I've heard that NGINX supports NTLM authentication, per [this blog post](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-plus-authenticate-users/), but while it talks about how to set it up, it doesn't go into much detail about how this actually works for web developers.

I have a few, specific questions about how NGINX Plus + LDAP / NTLM support works for web developers:

- Is it possible to perform user impersonation, similar to C# / .NET on IIS?
- Is it possible to authenticate to other resources, from a web application, as the user that's authenticated?
- Is it possible to obtain metadata about the directory and the user, such as the user's group memberships, or information about other users in Active Directory?
- If the above is possible, are certain languages / frameworks better than others for performing these tasks, versus others?